# Cocos2D removeChildByTag, tag belongs to whom?

Tags: iphone, tags, cocos2d-iphone, removechild

When I tell a CCNode:

```
[node addChild:child z:0 tag:5];
```

Assuming 5 is a unique tag number, calling:

```
[node removeChildByTag:5 cleanup:YES];
```

removes `child` .. but what if I wanted to change the tag of the child with respect to the parent (`node`) ?

Will changing `child.tag = 9` suffice? (i.e. calling `[node removeChildByTag:9 cleanup:YES];` removes `child` from `node`).

Thanks.

Comment: >.< ... I realize now how stupid this question is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know Cocos was open source!

Found this:

```
00345         CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, node){
00346                 if( node.tag == aTag )
00347                         return node;
00348         }
```

The obvious answer:

YES.

Comment: :) You might want to take a look at the cocos2d api reference - it's very helpful in such cases..: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_node.html#a4ed1d0596afb7822a87e41b75b496af3

Comment: Thanks, I even downloaded the offline reference!